# Pylint missclick string.strEp (string.strip) not detected

Tags: python, string, pylint

How can I config Pylint to detect this missclick?

```
str="dsdsdsdsds"
str1=str.splEt("d")
```

instead of

```
str1=str.split("d")
```

My config file:

```
[REPORTS]

reports=no

[MESSAGES CONTROL]

disable=W,R,C
```

Comment: Do you mean spelling error rather than missclick!?

Answer (score 0):

You mean getting a no-member error, because the attribute is missing? It already emits this, maybe you are disabling the error somewhere in pylintrc.

```
No config file found, using default configuration
************* Module a
C:  1, 0: Final newline missing (missing-final-newline)
C:  1, 0: Exactly one space required around assignment
str1=str.splEt("d")    ^ (bad-whitespace)
C:  1, 0: Missing module docstring (missing-docstring)
C:  1, 0: Invalid constant name "str1" (invalid-name)
E:  1, 9: Class 'str' has no 'splEt' member (no-member)
```

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution in pylintrc

```
[LOGGING]

logging-modules=logging
```